# Writing code in javadoc comment

Tags: java, html, javadoc

Is it possible to write a short code inside a java doc comment?

I don't mean a simple line of code, I mean a short method like:

```
public static void main() {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: You can write whatever you want, you can't execute it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in Multiple line comments like this.

```
/*
*  public static void main() {
*    doSomething();
*  }
/
```

If you want to be in Java documentation comment,then it would be with two `*` after slash

```
/**
*  public static void main() {
*    doSomething();
*  }
/
```

Comment: Did it help you to understand?